# Change a number field to a matching text field

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I change a number value in my report to show as one of a predetermined string?
For example, everything in the Status column with the content "1" changes to "Processing", everything with the content "2" changes to "Cancelled", everything with the content "3" changes to "Completed".
Also, can this be done in the interface or does it have to be done in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a formula field in crystal reports. the logic of the formula would be something like:

```
if ({myfield}=1) then "Processing"
else if ({myfield}=2) then "Cancelled"
else if ({myfield}=3) then "Completed"
```

then place that formula field in your report.